# Why do I get 401 UNAUTHORIZED when I'm entering to WSS 3.0 site?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, wss, wss-3.0

When I'm opening for the first time my webpage on WSS 3.0 I always get 401 UNAUTHORIZED.
I was trying a lot of resolutions from Google results. I disabled loop back check. Added administrator rights for sharepoint account. I have to add that I'm using anonymous access to default site.
Can anybody help me to resolve this issue? Please.

I was tried resolutions from here:
[codeplex](http://mossformsfeature.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=9702)
It didn't help as well. :(

Comment: This is a Superuser question.

Comment: @Clint - Not really superuser - setting up authentication is not really a user issue. More likely serverfault or sharepointoverflow

Comment: different stackoverflow like sights different focus - e.g. serverfault is for sysadmin type work rather than programming.

Comment: http://vspug.com/radi/2008/08/06/sharepoint-401-unauthorized-search-and-forms-authentication/

THIS IS A RESOLUTION!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is right resolution which helps:

[RESOLUTION!!](http://vspug.com/radi/2008/08/06/sharepoint-401-unauthorized-search-and-forms-authentication/)

```
<compilation batch="false" debug="false" />
```

Comment: How odd that the way the site recompiles itself impacts authorization.  Thanks for finding this.

Answer (score 0):

Note what zone the website is in IE. Sometimes due to the URL used (when URL has dots in it) IE would recognize the URL as belonging to the Internet zone and will not automatically pass your credentials. If so, add the site to the Intranet zone (IE, open the security tab of the Internet Options, click on Local Intranet, Advanced and add the URL of your site)

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable anonymous access on both the web application as well as the site collection for anonymous access to work. If you can accesss the site collection go to site settings/ under the users and groups section choose advanced permissions and choose settings/ anonymous access and set it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

On a couple instances I've run into... as a result of M$ updates, it sometimes does something internal to the internet user accounts such as

IWAM_{machineName}
IUSR_{machineName}

which are sometimes used internally by IIS as an account of the website.  It was as simple as clearing and resetting a password to these accounts and the site was active again without problems (until some future update associated with IIS messed the account again).